# How to get a computer-parseable (JSON preferably) feed of all new video game releases?

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, games

MobyGames has a "begware" API where you have to contact them and ask for access.

GameFAQs actively blocks scraper bots and appear to have no API whatsoever, and if they do, they probably charge through the nose.

I'm looking for some sort of reliable JSON blob which returns the 100 latest video games released, such as:

```
{
    "title": "Halo 123",
    "platform": "Xbox 1024",
    "developer": "Bungie",
    "publisher": "Microsoft",
    "genre": "FPS",
    "released-date": "2021-09-22",
    "URL": "https://www.halo123game.com/"
},
...
```

Does it exist? There is no way that I will try to keep up with these modern games in any kind of manual way, but if I can do this automated, I may pay some minimal interest in them.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question because I want to do the same thing! I found one promising website with an api along with documentation. [This](https://rawg.io/) is what I have found, I hope it helps with what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could scrape Wikipedia, for example by downloading an XML dump and searching for the "Infobox video game".